# How to provide configuration for Library (dll) which can be modified in Runtime application

Tags: c#, dll, config

I am working on a library that may be used in one or more runtime applications. This library has a function which searches a string for a set of "keys". If one is found, the return should return that key's value. If not found, return the original string.

```
protected string CorrectFloatingIndex(string indexDescription)
    {
        if (indexDescription== null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        foreach (var mapper in FloatingIndex.Mapping)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(indexDescription, mapper.Item1, 
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                return mapper.Item2;
            }
        }

        return indexDescription;
    }
```

I have currently been hard-coding the `FloatingIndex.Mapping` with a list of Tuples. When any `.Item1` is found, then return the associated `.Item2`.

```
public static class FloatingIndex
{
    public static List<Tuple<string, string>> Mapping = 
        new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
    {
        new Tuple<string, string>("TIIE", "TIIE"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("CAMARA PROMEDIO INDEX", "CAMAR"),
        new Tuple<string, string>("LIBOR", "LIBOR")
    };
}
```

This works fine; however when a new example of key-value pair is found and should be added to the list, this requires a change to the DLL, which then requires a new release of the runtime application using this DLL. This list will build over time as new key-value pairs are found are determined.

Keep in mind, the `CorrectFloatingIndex` method is used in the DLL. The runtime application does not use this method or the mapping table directly.

Is there a way to have a reference file or application configuration file which is located in the DLL (for testing and responsibility purposes), which cascades to the runtime application? This would allow testing and full functionality of the DLL while providing the runtime application the ability to provide updated key-value pairs to that file, without requiring releases.

Comment: Normal app.config keys can be implemented by the consumer of a library and will be picked up through `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: @JonathonChase Do you a good source which describes implementing this? I can't quite tell if it's what i'm looking for based on your comment but am interested in how it could be implemented.